# Using a Bat File to Open a New Window with Two Links

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the follow batfile.

```
@Echo Off
start firefox.exe "www.test.com" 
start firefox.exe "www.example.com"
```

I want to be able to click on this file. And then open new Firefox window and have both links visible as tabs. However, they way the code is now, the links will open any currently opened Firefox. I want them in a new window entirely. I attempted adding in -new-window, but when I did that, only one link opened in a new window.

Is there also a way to stop CMD from showing up on the screen for a flash second?

Comment: First of all your batch file only needed two lines, 1. `@Start "test" "P:\athTo\firefox.exe" "www.test.com"`, 2. `@Start "example" "P:\athTo\firefox.exe" "www.example.com"`. The code you have posted does not exhibit a reproducible issue, because it does not attempt the task you've laid out. If you want to run a batch file without the `cmd.exe` window appearing then the question has been asked and answered many times before. Please use the search facility at the top oi the page to find examples to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions#-url_URL), you can use the parameter -url multiple times at the same call. So you could achieve what you are looking for by using the parameters -new-window plus -url twice.

Example:

```
start firefox.exe --new-window --url "www.test.com" --url "www.example.com"
```

*Note: you may need to specify the firefox path at the command if you don't have it set in your PATH environment variable.*

Comment: Just to note, currently the question mentions that they have already used `-new-window`, but it only opened one link in a new window. However, we cannot see whether they really used `-new-window` or `--new-window`, and without their code, it is not possible for us to determine whether they have already tried what you have posted above, _(especially as it is clearly documented)_. Also in a single line it should look more like this: ```@Start "two links" "P:\athTo\firefox.exe" --new-window --url "www.test.com" --url "www.example.com"```.

Comment: thank worked. thank you

Comment: @Compo thanks. Actually by his description and code example I understood he tried to open the two links by calling "firefox [parameters]" twice, therefore it wouldn't open the two links in the same new window as he mentioned. So the solution was just to call "firefox" once followed by two " --url ww.sample.com " to achieve what he wanted. To be more practical, I just gave the full command. I'm gonna edit the answer to and put this explanation to be better clarified.